# how to change word press plugin labeling powered by at the bottom of it

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have installed tawk.to chat plugin into my word press site and it is showing a labeling powered by tawk.to in the bottom of it.how can i remove or change it.i have searched the code and link from cpanel but i am unable to find.

Comment: https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/advanced-features/remove-branding/

Comment: you need to pay for addon to remove branding

Comment: If you're using their free version version, then what's wrong with giving them something in return?